# Java encode and decode program cant pass key word through args

Tags: java, string, compare

So, I'm not sure what is happening here, if I place `encode` or `decode` in the `args[0]`, it should work right, but it doesn't. I have all the imports and I have a utility class that I'm using as well. I don't understand why, when I run the program with these arguments: `java Prog4 encode fly message.txt` it won't work right. It'll go straight to the last else statement.

```
    public class Prog4 {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            if (args.length != 3){
                    System.out.println("Enter the right amount of arguments!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }

            String command=args[0];
            String key= args[1];
            String fileName = args[2];
            File file = new File(args[2]);
            String fileExtention="";
            if(args[0]=="encode"){
                    fileExtention=".crypt";

            }
            else if (args[0]=="decode"){
                    fileExtention=".decrypt";
            }
            else{
                    System.out.println("Enter decode or encode!");
                    System.exit(0);
            }
```

Comment: You need to use the equals() method to compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
args[0].equals("encode")
```

and this:

```
args[0].equals("decode")
```

to compare the strings in java...

you use `==` to check if the references are equal.

you should use `.equals()` to check if the values are equal.

Comment: This worked! I'm so happy now thank you!

Comment: glad it works. please accept my answer by clicking the tick box on the left of my answer, below the arrows

Answer (score 0):

```
args[0]=="encode"
```

is WRONG!

it checks for object reference equality, not value equality!

use:

```
args[0].equals("encode");
```

or

```
args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("encode");
```

to ignore the case